# String cannot be entered

Tags: c

After printing "Second text", `fgets` expect from me to enter a *string* but a program is always being stopped. That happens when I try to enter *a char* by `scanf` or `getchar`. What's happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char c[100],cc;
int x;

printf("First text\n");

scanf("%d",&x);

printf("Second text\n");

fgets(c,100,stdin); 
   //scanf("%c",&cc);
   //cc=getchar();

printf("\n %s %d",c,x);

}
```

Comment: You're not even using `fgets`. This question is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I edited code. @melpomene

Comment: What do you mean by "a program is always being stopped"?

Comment: After I enter an integer, a program ends and I can't enter a string.  @melpomene

Answer (score 1):

You probably press "enter" after having entered a number; `scanf` will then read the number, but will leave a `'\n'` (i.e. the newline represening "enter") in the buffer; This will be treated as an "empty" line then by `gets`. (BTW: use `fgets` instead of `gets`).
To overcome this enter the number and the text seperated by a space in a single line (i.e. without a newline in between).